# Neo4j Cypher, different query results in code and database

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have a very peculiar problem. I have a query as follows

```
  var el = _client.Cypher.Match("(map:Map)-[ALSO_AS*0..4]-(alsoas:Map)")
               .Where((MappingNode map) => map.Id == node.Id)
               .Return((map, alsoas) => new
               {
                   node = map.As<MappingNode>(),
                   related = alsoas.CollectAs<MappingNode>()
               }); 
var query = el.Query;
        var result = el.Results.SingleOrDefault();
        return result == null ? null : result.related.ToList();
```

which ultimately generates following query (takem from el.Query)

```
MATCH (map:Map)-[ALSO_AS*0..4]-(alsoas:Map)
WHERE (map.Id = "02E325025AMZZ")
RETURN map AS node, collect(alsoas) AS related
```

The problem is that when i run the query in the browser in native command line of neo4j i get x number of results. While when i run the same query in the c# the result counts are 10times higher.

c# ( 1 node, ~3k related)
database (1 node, ~300 related)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that jumped out at me is that it looks like you're trying to match on the `ALSO_AS` relationship type, but since there's no colon it's interpreting it as a variable.  It should be like:

```
[:ALSO_AS*0..4]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved the problem.

```
var el = _client.Cypher.Match("(map:Map)-[r:ALSO_AS*0..4{ManCode :               {manCode}}]-(alsoas:Map)")
                .WithParams(new
                {
                    manCode = relation.ManCode
                })
               .Where((MappingNode map) => map.Id == node.Id)
               .Return((map, alsoas) => new
               {
                   node = map.As<MappingNode>(),
                   related = alsoas.CollectAsDistinct<MappingNode>()
               });
```

This is the solution in c#. What i was missing was distinct on collect and proper relationship declaration.